# Angular 2 submodule routing with AOT and Rollup

Tags: angular2-routing, angular2-aot, rollupjs

What is the correct way to configure a submodule in Angular 2 so that it will work after AOT and rollup? I'm not concerned about lazy loading and will be happy for all submodules to be bundled together, but `loadChildren` is the cleanest way of referencing a submodule and having it use the correct `<router-outlet>`, and although I've tried various methods, none will work in both development and production.

I followed the instructions in the [AOT cookbook](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html) to prepare my app for deployment. My module structure is root > account > admin, and I want the admin routes to load in the outlet defined by the account component.

Here's the router config for the account module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AdminModule }   from './admin/admin.module';

const accountRoutes: Routes = [{
    path: 'account',
    component: AccountComponent,
    children: [
        { path: 'setup', component: SetupComponent },
        { path: 'admin', loadChildren: () => AdminModule }
    ]
}];
```

This works in development, but NGC compilation fails with `Error: Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Reference to a local (non-exported) symbol 'accountRoutes'.`

I added an export to `accountRoutes` but this also fails to compile with `Error: Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Function calls are not supported.`.

One suggestion was to use a string instead of a function so that NGC can compile the code:

```
loadChildren: 'app/account/admin/admin.module#AdminModule'
```

This works in development and compiles successfully but the compiled app will not run, because SystemJS is unavailable. The error is:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: System.import is not a function
TypeError: System.import is not a function
at t.loadFactory (build.js:6)
at t.load (build.js:6)
at t.loadModuleFactory (build.js:12)
```

I tried including SystemJS in the production build but it could not find the separate module file `app/account/admin/admin.module.ngfactory` - after rollup everything is in one build.js. There may be a way to have separate rollups build each submodule, but that's a lot of work.

I found the suggestion of referring to an exported function:

```
export function loadAdminModule() {
    return AdminModule;
}

loadChildren: loadAdminModule
```

This works in development, but in production the runtime compiler is unavailable so it logs `build.js:1 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Runtime compiler is not loaded`.

The helper function can be modified so it works in production by referencing the NgFactory instead, but this won't work in development.

```
import { AdminModuleNgFactory }   from '../../../aot/src/app/account/admin/admin.module.ngfactory';

export function loadAdminModule() {
    return AdminModuleNgFactory;
}

loadChildren: loadAdminModule
```

Is there a supported way of using `loadChildren` so that it will work with the instructions in the AOT cookbook? Is it better to use webpack instead?

Comment: This question came up because I was following an official tutorial which used Rollup, shortly before the docs were updated to use Angular CLI, which doesn't have this problem. I migrated my project to Angular CLI.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone having the same problem, here's the temporary workaround I'm using. Hopefully a better answer will come along soon.

I now define my submodules in a dedicated file, `submodules.ts`. I have two versions of this file, `submodules-jit.ts` for development, and `submodules-aot.ts` for AOT/rollup deployment to production. I gitignore `submodules.ts` and have added commands to my `npm start` and `npm build:aot` scripts that substitute in the right one.

```
// submodules-jit.ts
import { AdminModule } from './account/admin/admin.module'
export function adminModule(): any { return AdminModule; }

// submodules-aot.ts
import { AdminModuleNgFactory } from '../../aot/src/app/account/admin/admin.module.ngfactory'
import { AdminModule } from './account/admin/admin.module'
export function adminModule(): any { return AdminModuleNgFactory; }
export function adminModuleKeep(): any { return AdminModule; }
```

AdminModule must be referenced in the AOT file so it is preserved.

Then I use the `adminModule` function in my routes:

```
import { adminModule } from '../submodules'
{ path: 'admin', loadChildren: adminModule }
```

Finally for convenience, npm scripts drop in the correct file.

```
"build:aot": "cp src/submodules-aot.ts src/app/submodules.ts && ngc -p tsconfig-aot.json && rollup -c rollup-config.js",
"start": "cp src/submodules-jit.ts src/app/submodules.ts && concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"npm run serve\""
```

Needless to say this is a horrible hack, but it keeps the routing files clean and most of the evil in one place.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I solved with your hint on loading routes from an external module, then reading [this issue on angular/cli issue page](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4192).

So, I came out refactoring my routes from:

```
import { TestModule } from './pathToModule/test.module';

export function exportTestModule() {
    return TestModule;
}

. . .

{
    path: 'test',
    loadChildren: exportTestModule
}
```

To:

```
. . .
{
    path: 'test',
    loadChildren: './pathToModule#TestModule'
}
```